# angularjs - building a login/launchpad that redirects to new app but maintains token info

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So far i have on `localhost/app1` the `main.html` page with `app.js` set up. Inside the `main.html` i have an `a` tag that goes to `localhost/app2`. The `app.js` contains a generated JWT token (e.g.: containing login or user information). The question is, how can i acces the JWT token on the `app2` angularjs application. Using cookies to store the token?
Don't like to use cookies with JWT token style authentication, and don't like to nest `app2` inside `app1` or load it dynamicly if i make `app3` for example.

Right now I'm saving the token with `$window.sessionStorage` and then referencing from `app2` the `app.js` (calling the module), which works, but is that the correct way to do it? Also any global variables that are set on `app.js` are undefined on `app2.js`, should they be inside `$window.sessionStorage` too?

p.s. Beginner regarding anguarjs and specially this having multiple angularjs apps sharing data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, anything that you want to put into the second app does need to be serialized and "saved" in some way.  You can use session storage, local storage or cookies for this task.

The downside to session storage is that it doesn't stick between tabs or in some cases during a refresh of the window.

Also, you may want to use a library to abstract session storage or local storage.  I have been using https://github.com/agrublev/angularLocalStorage for my app.

Comment: If using local storage, and the user closes the window, does the storage clears itself up?

Comment: No, it does not. In our app, we have a timestamp stored with the data and clear old data on the next visit to the app. However, it does waste space in the browser if the user leaves the site.

Comment: I finally got some time to implement the solution, i decided to use session storage & local storage. Right now i am using session storage to store json token info, and my other angular apps use dependency of the service that handles the storage. Gonna mark this as answer as it did help me understand the two storage options.